# Copy all parameters that implement this same interface

Tags: c#, interface

I am looking for best solution for example:
(lets talk using pseudo code!)

```
public interface IObj
{
    string propertyX;
    string propertyY;
}

public class ObjectA : IObj
{
    string propertyX;
    string propertyY;
}

public class ObjectB: IObj
{
    string propertyX;
    string propertyY;

    public ObjectB(ObjectA)
    {
        // HERE I WANT TO GET ALL Properties that are from ObjectA that is from IObj
        // without assigne this.propertyX=ObjectA.propertyX
    }
}
```

is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Bad idea, any "automagical" solution would most likely make your app go boom every time you touch ObjectA *or* ObjectB *or* IObj itself

Comment: Shouldn't you `ObjectB: ObjectA` ?

Comment: the problem is that i cant edit ObjectA and Interface i just need copy all Properties to ObjectB, but ObjectA has... some about 300 parameters from Interface IObj

Comment: I'd recommend changing `public ObjectB(ObjectA)` to `public ObjectB(IObj)`.  ObjectB should not have knowledge of ObjectA if it doesn't need it.  You state in your question that you only want information about `IObj`, so you should really change the signature to match that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do to accomplish your goal is:
- get all properties from `IObj` interface
- get all properties from `ObjectA` class
- get all properties from `ObjectB` class
- join the collections on property names from `IObj` interface and pair properties from `ObjectA` with properties from `ObjectB`
- iterate the pairs and call `GetValue()` on properties from `ObjectA` and `SetValue()` on properties from `ObjectB`

This is what I scratched in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new ObjectA
    {
        propertyX = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        propertyY = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    };
    var b = new ObjectB(a);
    b.Dump();
}


public interface IObj
{
    string propertyX{get;set;}
    string propertyY{get;set;}
}

public class ObjectA : IObj
{
    public string propertyX{get;set;}
    public string propertyY{get;set;}
}

public class ObjectB: IObj
{
    public string propertyX{get;set;}
    public string propertyY{get;set;}

    public ObjectB(ObjectA a)
    {
        var properties = typeof(IObj).GetProperties();
        var objAProperties = typeof(ObjectA).GetProperties();
        var objBProperties = typeof(ObjectB).GetProperties();
        var common = from p in properties
                     from propA in objAProperties
                     from propB in objBProperties
                     where p.Name == propA.Name && p.Name == propB.Name
                     select Tuple.Create(propA, propB);
        foreach(var tuple in common)
        {
            var value = tuple.Item1.GetValue(a);
            tuple.Item2.SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**LATER EDIT**

To create an extension method on interface:

```
public static class ObjExtesions
{
    public static void CopyProperties(this IObj source, IObj destination)
    {
        var properties = typeof(IObj).GetProperties();
        var objAProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
        var objBProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();
        var common = from p in properties
                     from propA in objAProperties
                     from propB in objBProperties
                     where p.Name == propA.Name && p.Name == propB.Name
                     select Tuple.Create(propA, propB);
        foreach(var tuple in common)
        {
            var value = tuple.Item1.GetValue(source);
            tuple.Item2.SetValue(destination, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, change code in `ObjectB` constructor:

```
public ObjectB(ObjectA a)
{
    a.CopyProperties(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but can you implement this code as an extension method to the interface?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a property named X in the class is the one implementing property X in the interface. You can just use the `p` value and read/write values of the two objects directly, you don't need to find properties on the classes themselves. Assuming, of course, that the classes in question actually implement the interface.

Comment: You cannot reliably implement it as an extension method of the interface, because it will be available on types implementing the interface, but the method will not be told which interface you were interested in.

Comment: I've added the extension method.